# Cannot see message on rabbitmq using EventBus.RabbitMQ.Standard

Tags: .net-core, configuration, rabbitmq, publish, event-bus

I'm start to learn about microservices with rabbitmq on .net core. I tried to understand how implement a simple way for publish and subscribe events, and i found a nuget with a samples on:
[Github EventBus.RabbitMQ.Standard](https://github.com/sayganov/EventBus.RabbitMQ.Standard)

I execute the **Publisher example** and consume URL for publish a simple event with this configuration:

```
"RabbitMq": {
"BrokerName": "test_broker",
"AutofacScopeName": "test_autofac",
"QueueName": "temp_queue",
"RetryCount": "5",
"VirtualHost": "/",
"Username": "guest",
"Password": "guest",
"Host": "localhost",
"DispatchConsumersAsync": true
```

}

Now works, **create the queue** and not generate a exception, but i **cannot see a message** on queue:
[image]

[image]

Nowadays with my knowledge about rabbitmq i dont know if **maybe is** a error on my **rabbit configuration** or if is a error on the nuget library.

**Any ideas about what may be happening?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error on my implementation.
I dont put on my Startup class (in Configure method) of my subscriber:

```
app.SubscribeToEvents();
```

Because that part not exists in the blog-github example documentation ;/ .

Answer (score 1):

Basically you won't see messages in a queue if there is no consumer(s).

1. Set up appsettings.json for a Publisher and a Subscriber
2. Run the Publisher and the Subscriber
3. Publish a message and see the message in the Subscriber
4. Stop the Subscriber app
5. Publish a new message and see the message in RabbitMQ Management

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the tutorials on their [website](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-dotnet.html) ?
It explains pretty clearly how to both publish and subscribe to `messages`, how exchanges,queues and routing keys work etc...